# Connect ESP8266 to subdomain website using Arduino UNO?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-uno, pythonanywhere

How to connect Arduino UNO, ESP8266 to a Subdomain website using AT commands?

Its working with
**ThingSpeak**,

```
AT+CIPMUX=1
AT+CIPSTART=1,"TCP","api.thingspeak.com",80
AT+CIPSEND=1,62
GET /update?api_key=myapikey&field1=123&field2=456
AT+CIPCLOSE=1
```

Now, I need to post a String data to a subdomain website using ESP8266, Arduino UNO
Example:
https://subdomain.pythonanywhere.com
http://3dgiftz.epizy.com

Thanks in advance

Comment: That would depend on what you are running there.

Comment: https://mysubdomain.pythonanywhere.com/page13?hello=10. I need my ESP8266 to call this

Comment: Have you tried modifying the code you posted to do that?

Comment: Yes tried modifying AT commands but didnt work. Or anyidea on how to connect esp8266 to a subdomain website hosted by infinityfree.net. Here is the subdomain php website.(http://3dgiftz.epizy.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to upload ESP8266 content to subdomain.pythonanywhere.com in 3 Steps

**FOLLOW CAREFULLY**

Step1:-
[ThingHTTP APP for subdomain.pythonanywhere.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjkjn.png)

Step2:-
[change settings.py in pythonanywhere.com to avoid {%csrf_token%} error because ThingHTTP is using POST method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBm8W.png)

Step3:-
AT commands

```
AT+CIPMUX=1
AT+CIPSTART=1,"TCP","api.thingspeak.com",80
AT+CIPSEND=1,76
GET /apps/thinghttp/send_request?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&busid=ABC123&nfc=ABDE3456
AT+CIPCLOSE=1
```

Reference:
[thinghttp-app.html documentation](https://in.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/thinghttp-app.html) (step-1)
[https://exceptionshub.com/how-to-disable-djangos-csrf-validation](https://exceptionshub.com/how-to-disable-djangos-csrf-validation.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20disable%20the%20CSRF%20to%20make%20your,def%20process_request%20%28self%2C%20request%29%3A%20setattr%20%28request%2C%20%27_dont_enforce_csrf_checks%27%2C%20True%29)(step-2)

ESP8266 Connection to Arduino UNO (step-3)

```
Arduino --------------------------------------- ESP8266  
Pin 0 (RX) -----------------------------------> RXD  
Pin 1 (TX) -----------------------------------> TXD  
GND ------------------------------------------> GND  
3.3 V ----------------------------------------> VCC  
3.3 V ----------------------------------------> CH_PD
```

Upload Simple Arduino Code

```
void setup() {  
// put your setup code here, to run once:    

}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```